# Output escaping in Symfony

Tags: php, escaping, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2 project running and have a problem with output escaping in one of my DB calls.

The thing is, I am not retrieving a PHP object in my Doctrine query, but rather an array in PHP. The reason why I am doing this is another topic altogether, let's just say getting a PHP object would not be the solution. Essentially the query is an inner join between two doctrine models. Model 1 inner joins with Model 2 and the results yielded can be accessed like this:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
 echo $result['field1']; // accessing results for model 1 
 echo $result['model2']['field1']; // accessing results for model 2 (this inner joins with the model)
}
```

Now for the above, more specifically for model2, field1 consists of HTML markup, which is naturally output escaped. I need the HTML markup to be rendered as it is! Which is where the problem lies,

if this was a regulation Doctrine object, a simple $modelObject->getRawValue()->getField(); would render HTML markup without escaping it. I am not sure how HTML markup can be rendered in a PHP array?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder, if you `print_r($result)` inside your loop, you might find it is wrapped in an escaper object. If so, you should be able to use `getRawValue()` on its elements as well?

Comment: Halfer, most of your solutions are comments, how do I accept those as answers ?

Comment: If you see a comment that works for you, just ask the poster to copy their comment into an answer, and accept! I do it all the time. If that helped, then great - been there, scratched my head for ages `:-)`.

Comment: Halfer post the comment as an answer, you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from my earlier comment). I wonder, if you `print_r($result)` inside your loop, you might find it is wrapped in an escaper object. If so, you should be able to use `getRawValue()` on its elements as well?

This works because the escaper object implements the `Iterator` interface (so you can do the `foreach` over it) and also `ArrayAccess` (so it appears to work like an array).